# How to use material ui dropzone into my react with typescript application?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, dropzone

Button on click should open the mui dropzone which helps me import files.

I tried adding the components from https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-dropzone?activeTab=readme but it does not work and provides the below error.

```
const DropzoneDialog: React.ComponentType<DropzoneDialogProps>
import DropzoneDialog
'DropzoneDialog' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<DropzoneDialogProps, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<DropzoneDialogProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<DropzoneDialogProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types
```

Comment: If you're using `React 18`. This library does not support it properly, because it was last updated in `2020`.  There are so many similar open issues on this library on their github page. I suggest finding a replacement for this library for your project.

Comment: The `material-ui-dropzone` is just a wrapper around the `react-dropzone`. It'e better you use `react-dropzone` directly `https://react-dropzone.js.org/`. You can customise and make it looks as you want.

Comment: @SimranSingh I am using   "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",  and  "@mui/material": "^5.0.0"

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` by editing your question?

Comment: @SimranSingh it is probably due to the mui version supported but I need the exact functionality as material-ui-dropzone to be used to import json files

version  React          Material-UI
3.x          16.8+          4.x
2.x          15.x or 16.x  3.x or 4.x

Comment: @SimranSingh do you have any package suggestions for swapping mui dropzone, I use "typescript": "^4.5.4" ,"@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.0", "@mui/material": "^5.0.0", "@mui/styles": "^5.0.0", "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.4",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.3",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.14.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.11.4",
    "react-resizable": "^3.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "react-use-trigger": "^0.3.4",
    "reactflow": "^11.7.1",

Comment: https://react-dropzone.js.org/#section-basic-example